# Remote logging from snort to rsyslog

Tags: ubuntu, logging, remote, rsyslog, snort

As part of a school project, we are supposed to run snort on a Ubuntu server in IDS mode and log the packets to rsyslog on a remote Ubuntu server. I have been searching for manuals/tutorials for a week now. I couldn't find any helpful links. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting at the man pages.  Also, there is documentation about snort on its website www.snort.org.  As for rsyslog, there is site for that as well, www.rsyslog.com.

I'm a bit surprised that neither of these two sources would not provide you with the information you needed.